# How to diagnose matrix error in C which utilises shared memory?

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory

I am trying to create a program that can multiply 2 `2x2` matrixes using separate processes (`child1` and `child2`). Specifically `child`1 processes `row1` of the resulting matrix and `child2` processes `row`2 of the resulting matrix. This resulting matrix is stored in shared memory.

However during the testing of `child1` which is yet to be completed, it is expected to write to the top row (`row1`) of the resulting matrix but it is showing that the nested loop is writing `660` into the second row as shown below.

```
Resulting Matrix2 from code
220              660     
660               0
```

**Expected matrix from `child1`**

```
  220     660     
    0     0
```

**test.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "shm_com.h"


//signal handler should be void of return type
void sig_handler(int signo){
    printf("Inside handler function\n");
}

int main(){
    int PROCESS_COUNT = 0;
    bool display = false;
    int row, column, limit=2;
    int M[2][2] = {     {20, 20,},
                    {10, 6,}};
    int N[2][2] = {     {10, 30,},
                    {1, 3,}};
    int Matrix_Size1=sizeof(M)/sizeof(int);
    int Matrix_Size2=sizeof(N)/sizeof(int);
    if(Matrix_Size1==Matrix_Size2) printf("Matrixes are the same size\n");
    

    int shmid;
    void *shared_memory = (void *)0;
    struct shared_use_st *shared_stuff;
    shmid = shmget((key_t)9998, sizeof(struct shared_use_st), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    //Creation of Shared Memory
    if (shmid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "shmget failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    pid_t pid1,pid2;
    pid1 = fork();
    PROCESS_COUNT = 1;
    if(pid1!=0){
        pid2 = fork();
        PROCESS_COUNT = 2;
    }
    //Warning code after this point will be included into child unless in if statement

    if ((PROCESS_COUNT == 1 && pid1==0) || (PROCESS_COUNT == 2 && pid2 == 0)){
        /* child1 ------------------------------------------------------------*/
        if(PROCESS_COUNT == 1){
            printf("Child 1 Process: working with Q's 1 row\n");
            //sleep(10);
            //Get access to shared memory
            shared_memory = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
            if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if(display){printf("Child Memory attached at %X\n", (int)shared_memory);}
            shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;
            for(column=0; column<limit; column++){
                for (row=0; row<limit; row++){
                
                    shared_stuff->Q_matrix[0][column] += M[0][column]*N[row][column];
                    printf("check %d   ",shared_stuff->Q_matrix[0][column]);
                    //printf("check Row:%d,Column: %d   ",row,column);
                }
                if(display){printf("Row1_Q_matrix \n");}
                printf("\n");
                
            }
        //kill(pid1, SIGALRM);
        exit(1);
        }
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /* child2 */
        else if(PROCESS_COUNT == 2){
            printf("Child 2 Process: working with Q's 2 row\n");
            //Get access to shared memory
            shared_memory = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
            if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if(display){printf("Child Memory attached at %X\n", (int)shared_memory);}
            shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;
    
        }
    } else {
        /* parent ------------------------------------------------------------*/    
        if(display){printf("Parent pid: %i PROCESS_COUNT: %i \n  ", getpid(),PROCESS_COUNT);}

        //Get access to shared memory
        shared_memory = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
        if (shared_memory == (void *)-1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "shmat failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(display){printf("Parent Memory attached at %X\n", (int)shared_memory);}
        shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;

        //Write number to shared memory------------------------------------------------*/
        
        
        
        //Write and Display M matrix
        for (row=0; row<limit; row++)
        {
            for(column=0; column<limit; column++){
                shared_stuff->M_matrix[row][column] = M[row][column];
                if(display){printf("%d     ", (shared_stuff->M_matrix[row][column]));}
            }
            if(display){printf("M_matrix \n");}
            printf("\n");
            
        }
        //Write and Display N matrix
        for (row=0; row<limit; row++)
        {
            for(column=0; column<limit; column++){
                shared_stuff->N_matrix[row][column] = N[row][column];
                if(display){printf("%d     ", (shared_stuff->N_matrix[row][column]));}
            }
            if(display){printf("N_matrix \n");}
            printf("\n");
         }
        //Write and Display Q matric
        printf("Written Matrix\n");
        for (row=0; row<limit; row++)
        {
            for(column=0; column<limit; column++){
                shared_stuff->Q_matrix[row][column] = 0;
                printf("%d     ", (shared_stuff->Q_matrix[row][column]));
            }
            if(display){printf("Q_matrix");}
            printf("\n");
         }
        wait(NULL);
        sleep(10);
        printf("Resulting Matrix2\n");
        printf("%d     ", (shared_stuff->Q_matrix[0][0]));
        printf("%d     \n", (shared_stuff->Q_matrix[0][1]));
        printf("%d     ", (shared_stuff->Q_matrix[1][0]));
        printf("%d     \n", (shared_stuff->Q_matrix[1][1]));
        /*for (row=0; row<limit; row++){
            for(column=0; column<limit; column++){
                printf("%d     ", (shared_stuff->Q_matrix[row][column]));
            }
            if(display){printf("Q_matrix");}
            printf("\n");
         }*/
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    printf("done\n");
    }
    
}
```

---

Here is my structure of shared memory:

```
#define TEXT_SZ 2048
struct shared_use_st {
    int M_matrix[1][1];
    int N_matrix[1][1];
    int Q_matrix[1][1];
};
```

---

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong? It looks like the memory address for spot Q_matrix[0][1] is the same as the Q_matrix[1][0]?

Answer (score 0):

Both `Q_matrix[0][1]` and `Q_matrix[1][0]` are invalid; the "matrix" is a 1x1 matrix, so the only valid index is `Q_matrix[0][0]`.

Regardless, because the second dimension is only size 1, you'd *expect* the indexing to produce the same address. In one case, you're asking for an address one `int` later, in the other, for an address one `int[1]` later, but an `int` and an `int[1]` are the same size, so the addressing gets the same result.

I suspect you intended to declare a `Q_matrix[2][2]` (for which `0` and `1` are legal indices in both dimensions), not `Q_matrix[1][1]` (for which `0` is the only legal index in either dimension).

Comment: This is true i did intend to make Q_matrix [2][2] however when updating the structure with your suggestion, then i get: 

"shmget failed"

I don't see why shmget would be failing to create shared memory then/

Comment: @Rambus: I might suggest rebooting, to make sure the problem isn't that you're asking for an existing shared memory segment with known size, but asking for it to be a different size. My experience with shared memory isn't extensive, but the whole "not directly tied to the lifetime of a single program" can cause all sorts of issues.